# What happens to a pointer dereferenced in the return statement?

Tags: c++, pointers, return

This is a question related to homework. It is not the homework itself, which I have completed.

Here's part of a function (the only pieces that I think relevant).

```
double mean(double* pD, int* sz) {
    double *meanPtr = new double;
    *meanPtr = 0.0;
    return *meanPtr; //how to deal with a memory leak in return statement? does it leak?
}
```

I'm concerned about the last bit. Does this result in a memory leak as I haven't pointed to null or deleted the pointer?

Comment: Yes. It is a memory leak since you never free the memory with delete.

Comment: Why are you using `new` at all?  If you *must* use a pointer for some reason, then use a smart pointer, like `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to solve exactly this problem than do like this

```
double mean(double* pD, int* sz) {
    double mean = 0.0;
    return mean;
}
```

If this is just an example and you need to use pointers, then return a pointer. You can wrap it in `std::shared_ptr` to prevent manual memory control.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into std::shared_ptr. It is just an example where I needed to use pointers.

Comment: *"You can wrap it in `std::shared_ptr` to prevent manual memory control."* - Typo, you meant `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the pointer-part is fixed, you can do this.

```
double mean(double* pD, int* sz) {
    double *meanPtr = new double;
    *meanPtr = 0.0;
    // Code above is assumed to be a given.
    double result = *meanPtr;
    delete meanPtr
    return result;
}
```

Modern compilers spot that `result` is just the name of the return value, and generate efficient code for that. (NRVO, Named Return Value Optimization)

Answer (score 2):

> does it leak?

Of course it does leak like hell.

> how to deal with a memory leak in return statement

I can't imagine a scenario when it would be valid to structure your code like this - simply **don't do this.** Why not just

```
return 0.0;
```

or

```
double foo = 0.0;
return foo;
```

?

Comment: It's a good point. There's no good reason for it beyond the academic. I'll avoid structuring code like this.