# Why shouldn't a C++ method return a dereferenced pointer?

Tags: c++, dereference

I'm very new to C++ (and studying Java).  This is from HW but I think I've answered the HW issue and I'm just trying to get a better sense of pointers.

Say I have the following method:

```
int cubed(int a) {
  int * ptr;
  *ptr = a * a * a;
  return *ptr;
}
```

This compiles and works fine with the following:

```
int test = cubed(3);
```

I'm trying to get a sense of why it's bad to return a dereferenced pointer.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382655/what-happens-to-a-pointer-dereferenced-in-the-return-statement) says that memory leak is a problem but I'm not sure why.  Maybe because I don't understand what happens to a dereferenced pointer.

Does the lvalue just hang around indefinitely at that point?  Do you have to actually delete the pointer?  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem here is that you're writing to an `int` that doesn't exist. Never mind dereferencing: there's no memory leak here because you do not allocate any memory that can be leaked (which just makes things _worse_). Your code is not equivalent to the code in the question you link. What book are you using?

Comment: Assigning to a de-referenced, uninitialized pointer sounds like a pretty crazy thing to do. If that doesn't generate a warning, you need to turn on more warnings.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not using a book yet, just trying to figure this out on my own.

Comment: @tadman I'm using Xcode.  I'm used to Eclipse for Java.  Xcode is offering no warnings and when there is an error it's not suggesting any solutions like Eclipse does - that really helps with the learning.  This code compiles, runs and displays `temp` as 27.

Comment: At the very least you'll need [The Book on C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html). There's a lot of other references that help learning the finer points of the Standard Library or proper memory management, but that one is invaluable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question you read is different. Say you had this code:

```
int cubed(int a) {
  int* ptr = new int;
  *ptr = a * a * a;
  return *ptr;
}
```

Now, you'd be leaking the dynamically-allocated `int`, because you'd return a copy of it and never `delete` the original.

Your code is actually *worse* because, instead of allocating with `new`, you're simply writing through an uninitialised pointer to memory that is not yours. In effect, you're writing to an `int` that does not exist.

What you *should* be doing is this:

```
constexpr int cubed(const int a)
{
   return a*a*a;
}
```

Or just invoke `std::pow(value, 3)` at the call site.

Answer (score 1):

There is no memory link in your code, but there is another big bug.

You declare `int * ptr;` inside the function `int cubed(int a)`, so it is a local variable.

The value of `ptr` will be random - might be NULL, might point to garbage, might point to some perfectly valid address. You don't initialize the variable `ptr`, so your code will sometimes crash.